# How to disable validation on form reset react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-final-form, final-form

I have custom validation in email input field, which is being triggered by `form.reset()`, which reset the form (After user successfully submit form).

I was wondering how to not trigger validation after user submit and reset the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following method to get rid of validation after successfully submission and resetting of the form.

```
form.reset();
form.resetFieldState('email');
```

It's available under

> FormRenderProps > FormApi

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into this issue in future - you could also use `form.restart()` which will both reset the form and field state for all fields. This is perfect for when your initial form values trigger validations.

[See FormAPI docs here](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi)